# Unit Testing with Fluent nHibernate - Delete Data for Each Test Possibilities

Tags: c#, unit-testing, fluent-nhibernate, nunit

I have set up some In Memory SQLite Unit Tests for my Fluent NHibernate Database, which looks like this. It works fine. (Using `NUnit`)

```
namespace Testing.Database {
    /// <summary>
    /// Represents a memory only database that does not persist beyond the immediate
    /// testing usage, using <see cref="System.Data.SQLite"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public abstract class InMemoryDatabase : IDisposable {
        /// <summary>
        /// The configuration of the memorized database.
        /// </summary>
        private static Configuration Configuration { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// The singleton session factory.
        /// </summary>
        protected static ISessionFactory SessionFactory { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// The current session being used.
        /// </summary>
        protected ISession Session { get; set; }

        protected InMemoryDatabase() {
            SessionFactory = CreateSessionFactory();
            Session = SessionFactory.OpenSession();
            BuildSchema(Session);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Construct a memory based session factory.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>
        /// The session factory in an SQLite Memory Database.
        /// </returns>
        private static ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory() {
            return FluentNHibernate.Cfg.Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(FluentNHibernate.Cfg.Db.SQLiteConfiguration
                .Standard
                .InMemory()
                .ShowSql())
            .Mappings(mappings => mappings.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Data.Mappings.AspectMap>())
            .ExposeConfiguration(configuration => Configuration = configuration)
            .BuildSessionFactory();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Builds the NHibernate Schema so that it can be mapped to the SessionFactory.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="Session">
        /// The <see cref="NHibernate.ISession"/> to build a schema into.
        /// </param>
        private static void BuildSchema(ISession Session) {
            var export = new NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport(Configuration);
            export.Execute(true, true, false, Session.Connection, null);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Dispose of the session and released resources.
        /// </summary>
        public void Dispose() {
            Session.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

So now, in order to use it, I just inherit `InMemoryDatabase` and add my Test methods, like this.

```
[TestFixture]
    public class PersistenceTests : InMemoryDatabase {
        [Test]
        public void Save_Member() {
            var member = // ...;
            Session.Save(member); // not really how it looks, but you get the idea...
        }
    }
```

My problem isn't that this doesn't work. It does. But if I have two tests in the same class that test similar data, for instance ...

`Username_Is_Unique()` and then `Email_Is_Unique()`. Not real tests again, but it's a good example.

```
[Test]
public void Username_Is_Unique(){ 
   var user = new User { 
         Name = "uniqueName"
         Email = "uniqueEmail"
   };

   // do some testing here... 
}
[Test]
public void Email_Is_Unique(){ 
   var user = new User { 
         Name = "uniqueName"
         Email = "uniqueEmail"
   };

   // do some testing here... 
}
```

## I realize these are very bad tests. These are not real tests, I am just citing an example.

In both cases, I would construct a mock `User` or `Member` or what-have you and submit it to the database.

The first one works fine, but since the database is in memory (which makes sense, since I told it to be), the second one doesn't. Effectively, the Unit Tests do not reflect real-world situations, because each test stands alone. But when running them sequentially in a batch, it behaves like it should in the real world (I suppose that's partially a good thing)

What I want to do is flush the in memory database after each method. So I came up with a simple way to do this by repeating the constructor. This goes in the `InMemoryDatabase` class.

```
protected void Restart() {
            SessionFactory = CreateSessionFactory();
            Session = SessionFactory.OpenSession();
            BuildSchema(Session);
        }
```

So now, in each method in my inheriting class, I call `Restart()` before I do my testing.

I feel like this isn't the intended, or efficient way to solve my problem. Can anyone propose a better solution?

If it is of any relevance, I am using `Fluent nHibernate` for the persistence, and `Telerik JustMock` for my Mocking - but for my database stuff, I've yet to need any mocking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to drop and recreate the database for every test. Every test should be independent of the other. You can do do two thing, first have your test use a setup method (Assuming NUnit here but others have the same functionality)

```
    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        // Create in memory database
        Memdb = new InMemoryDatabase();
    }
```

Alternatively, you can wrap each test in a using statement for the database. For example

```
[Test]
public void Test()
{
    using(var db = new InMemmoryDatabase())
    {
      Do Some Testing Here
    }
}
```